# Where does terminal look for its commands?

Tags: terminal, symlink

I've just installed pypy, and I've made a symlink from `/pypy` to my pypy installation.

How can I turn this into a command, so that I can just type `pypy myfile.py`
instead of having to type `/pypy myfile.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are on Snow leopard or on Lion the way to do it is as follows:

go to `/etc/paths.d` then

```
sudo touch pypy
```

then edit the pypy file (with vim, nano or whatever) to include the path to `pypy`

```
/path/to/pypy
```

the restart the terminal. For instance, I installed julia (http://julialang.org/) and I added a julia file in paths.d

```
$ cd /etc/paths.d
$ ls 
50-X11   MacGPG2  TeX      TeXbin   git      julia
$ cat julia 
/usr/local/julia
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your shell. Check your $SHELL and $PATH variables

Symlinks should be executable by default, so you might just link your pypy to a directory already in your path. /usr/local/bin is a good choice for this sort of thing unless you have more intricate needs to separate things.

Comment: I've currently stored the binary next to the python framework, so I believe it's in /system/lybrary/frameworks, there I've created a directory called pypy, which now stores that. I'll look into the variables now.

Comment: I think I should add my pypy directory to the $PATH variable, looking up how to do that now.

Comment: I've edited my .profile file, so that it contains `export PATH=/pypy:$PATH` but that doesn't work.